# Prove that $\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}=\dfrac{1}{2.2!}+\dfrac{3}{3.3!}+\dfrac{5}{3.4!}+\dfrac{8}{3.5!}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

My first approach was to try and convert the summation into a derived result of the Basel problem. However I couldn't find a link and used a mix of polynomial and trigonometric functions to represent the LHS.

Assumed:
$\arctan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{1.2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2.3}+\dfrac{x^3}{3.4}+\cdots\right)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots$

$a_2=\frac{1}{2.2!}$;$a_3=\frac{3}{3.3!}$;$a_4=\frac{5}{3.4!}$;$a_5=\frac{8}{3.5!}$

I am not sure if the derived result is correct. I would appreciate any alternate derivations that either prove or disprove the result. Additionally, I would like to know if the RHS might somehow be connected to the Basel problem.

Comment: I don't undestand the rule of the terms . which is the next term?

Comment: $a_2=\frac{1}{2.2!}$;$a_3=\frac{1}{1.3!}$;$a_4=\frac{5}{3.4!}$;$a_5=\frac{8}{3.5!}$. 
Even I'm unsure about the pattern but these are their alternate representations. They  do seem to follow a pattern but the online derivative calculator doesn't allow me to find out more than 5 coefficients so I'm not sure yet :)

Comment: But if you don't specify the pattern, what are we to prove?

Comment: Judging from the coefficients I would say that $\frac{a3}{a2}=\frac{2}{3}$; $\frac{a4}{a3}=\frac{5}{12}$;  $\frac{a5}{a4}=\frac{8}{25}$

These quotients do seem to follow a pattern; $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}.2$;   $\frac{5}{12}=\frac{1}{4}.\frac{5}{3}$;  $\frac{8}{25}=\frac{1}{5}\frac{8}{5}$

The numerators seem to increment by 3 and the denominators are the n+1 from $\frac{a_(n+1)}{a_n}$

Comment: Oh I forgot the second part of the denominator. It also increments by 2 every iteration. However I might require derivative calculators capable of handling lots of variables to verify that the series does hold :)

Comment: Use `\cdot` and not `.` for multiplication, so they don't look like decimal points.

Answer (score 2):

Assumed

$\arctan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{1.2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2.3}+\dfrac{x^3}{3.4}+\cdots\right)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots$

The resulting coefficients are $a_0=0; a_1=0$(Since LHS is also missing x coefficients) $a_2=\frac{1}{4}; a_3=\frac{1}{6}; a_4=\frac{5}{72}; a_5=\frac{8}{360}$

When $x=1$; the LHS becomes $\arctan^2(1)=\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)^2=\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}$

Since
$a_2=\frac{1}{2.2!}$;$a_3=\frac{3}{3.3!}$;$a_4=\frac{5}{3.4!}$;$a_5=\frac{8}{3.5!}$

Following the pattern, $a_6=\frac{8.11}{25.7.6!}$; $a_7=\frac{88.14}{25.7.9.7!}$ ;$a_8=\frac{8.11.14.17}{25.7.9.11.8!}...$

The RHS becomes:

$\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{5}{72}+\dfrac{8}{360}+\cdots$

Therefore;

$\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{5}{72}+\dfrac{8}{360}+\dfrac{44}{525}+\dfrac{11}{70875}+\cdots$

Comment: Interesting to notice that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n (n+1)}=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \log (1-x)$$ which means that, making $x=\frac{297}{379}$ we obtain $\frac{\pi ^2}{36}$ for an absolute error of $5.42\times 10^{-8}$.